# making the frame title more informative

Tags: frame-title-format

The frame title I can see in an emacs window on my computer running Windows 11 is "emacs@NEYMAN", where "Neyman" is the computer name.  Is it possible to make the frame title more informative and reflect the contents of the file?  Ideally, I would like to be able to specify the frame title in one of the first lines of the text file.

The reason I am asking is that I am accustomed to never combining taskbar buttons in Windows 10, but Windows 11 has removed this option.  When I hover over a combined emacs button on the taskbar, I am shown the frame titles of all open emacs files, and those titles don't give me any idea of the files' contents.

There is a section (C.11 in my version) about frame titles in "GNU Emacs Manual", but I can't see how I can customize the frame title for an individual file.

Comment: You can also use `frame-title-format` to specify what is displayed in the title bar. I have the following in my .emacs file `(setq-default frame-title-format '("%& %b [%m] %f - " invocation-name "@" system-name))`

Comment: @rsp: Thank you, I like the option `(setq-default frame-title-format '("%b"))` a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [file-variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) for this, at the start or at the end of your file (as explained in the manual).

For example in a bash file, where `#` is used for comments, you can set the frame title statically, e.g. by adding the following line at the beginning of the file

```
# -*- frame-title-format: "new title" -*-
```

Or you can set it dynamically using e.g.

```
# -*- eval : (setq frame-title-format (buffer-file-name)) -*-
```

In a .c file, you can use

```
/* -*- frame-title-format: "new title" -*- */
```

etc.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: You can see that I am not knowledgeable in emacs (despite using it all the time).  It would be great not to be asked to confirm that I do want to set the risky local variable "frame-title-format" every time I open the file.  However, I am not given the "!" option (only "y" and "n").  Is there a simple way of achieving this?

Comment: You can find that answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/18785/26163), and read more about it [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Safe-File-Variables.html)

Comment: Thank you; the first link is particularly useful for non-expert readers like me.

Comment: The answer in the comment by @rsp seems a generally more elegant solution to me (I was not aware of that option as I actually never have wanted to change the frame title, yet)